# JavaScript - Passing Arguments to Anonymous Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling an anonymous function:

```
        closeSidebar(function() {
            alert("function called");
            $(this).addClass("current");
            setTimeout(function(){openSidebar()}, 300);
        });
```

But `$(this)` doesn't work as expected and I need to pass it as an argument into the function. After a bit of research I thought this would work:

```
            closeSidebar(function(el) {
               $(el).addClass("current");
               setTimeout(function(){openSidebar()}, 300);
            })(this);
```

But it doesn't. How do I add arguments to an anonymous function?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Mxs/13/) - Click a button on the right, it animates in then calls the function above. When the button has the class "current" it will have a white bar on the left side of the button but the class never changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
        closeSidebar(function(el) {
            $(el).addClass("current");
            setTimeout(function(){openSidebar()}, 300);
        }(this));
```

The arguments need to be passed to the anonymous function itself, not the caller.

Comment: This is valid syntax? And here I thought `closeSidebar(function (el) {} (this));` would *at best* call the function and pass its return to `closeSidebar`.

Answer (score 5):

You can refer below code for passing parametrs in anonymous function.

```
var i, img;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(someIndex)
  {
    someFunction(someIndex);
  }(i);
  img.src = imagePaths[i];
}
```

Hope u will get some idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method for adding arguments:

```
var fn=function() { };
fn.apply(this,arguments);
```